# How to sort dictionary values from Highest to lowest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, key

My question would be how I withdraw winner based on highest score?
since u cant sort in dictionaries 
i tried this with lists, but then name wouldnt appear, only the score...

```
a = {'name_a':0}
b = {'name_b':0}
c = {'name_c':0}
d = {'name_d':0}
e = {'name_e':0}

print("Each time someone scores a point, the letter of his name is typed in lowercase. If someone loses a point, the letter of his name is typed in uppercase")


score = input('Enter series of charachters indicating who scored a poitn: ')

for i in score:
    if i == 'a':
        a['name_a'] += 1
    if i == 'A':
        a['name_a'] -= 1
    if i == 'b':
        b['name_b'] += 1
    if i == 'B':
        b['name_b'] -= 1
    if i == 'c':
        c['name_c'] += 1
    if i == 'C':
        c['name_c'] -= 1
    if i == 'd':
        d['name_d'] += 1
    if i == 'D':
        d['name_d'] -= 1
    if i == 'e':
        e['name_e'] += 1
    if i == 'E':
        e['name_e'] -= 1

print(a,b,c,d,e)

print('Winner is: ', )
```

Comment: Your data structure could be a single dictionary like `{'a': 0, 'b': 0}` etc. which would simplify the code a lot

Comment: @Chris_Rands ty for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to use a single dict, instead of one for each, like such:

```
scores = {
    'a': 0,
    'b': 0,
    'c': 0,
    'd': 0,
    'e': 0,
}
```

And then you can keep track of the highest scoring player as points are calculated:

```
point_scored = input('Enter series of charachters indicating who scored a point: ')


for i in point_scored:
    if not scores.get(i) is None:
        scores[i] += 1
    elif not scores.get(i.lower()) is None:
        scores[i.lower()] -= 1
    else:
        print(str(i) + ' is not a valid player...')

winner = max(scores, key=scores.get)

print(scores)

print('Winner is ' + winner)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try to apply it :)

Comment: I agree this is the way to go, but you need to handle upper case letter `-= 1`

Comment: Also `scores = dict.fromkeys('abcde', 0)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands You are correct, I just skimmed and read it as handle both upper and lowercase, not them doing the different things. Also thanks for showing that way of initiating dicts, that super neat!

Comment: @GvidoKārlisŠķuburs as Chris has pointed out, my solution only accounts for adding points, not removing them, which complicates it a bit more and no longer makes it the optimal way to do it. You may need to recalculate highest scores using one of the other listed ways at the end

Comment: @GvidoKārlisŠķuburs I've updated the solution, it now works with addition and subtraction, and calculates very easily the max score

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

`max((i, name) for d in (a,b,c,d,e) for name, i in d.items())[1]`

Comment: @ÑØØLÌÊ please don't ask for reputation like that, moderator will flag your comment.

Comment: It's nice, I would suggest him to actually turn it into a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
max_key = ""
max_val = 0

for key, value in d.items():
    if (value > max_val):
        max_val = value
        max_key = key
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer

```
winner = (sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse  = True))
```